# Wanna Scale up contents inside the view according the size of the view, which chages according to the device

Tags: objective-c, uiview

I share same storyboard for iPad and iPhone. I have contents inside a small view. I Wanna Scale up contents inside that view according the size of the view, which changes according to the device it's been installed.

Answer (score 1):

try to set autoresizing masks like

```
[YourView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
```

Hope will help this

Comment: I dropped this idea and switched to other idea bcaz of ui changes. Yet I'll try this in my sample app and get back to you. Thanks for your help.